# Unable to use record

Tags: graalvm-native-image

Completely new to graal-native-image, trying to familiarize with that.
According to documentation I'm using tests and agent to create explicit metadata. It discovered reflection and and even some c libraries and it works. But java record does not. I have it fully covered by tests, so agent stepped on everything. Record instance is created by JacksonMapper, and even that flow is covered by tests.

record looks like this:

```
record Issue(String a, String b, String c, String d) {}
```

generated metadata contains (I'm selecting interesting parts):

```
{
  "name":"a.b.c.D$Issue",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredConstructors":true,
  "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":["java.lang.String","java.lang.String","java.lang.String","java.lang.String"] }]
}

...

{
  "name":"java.lang.Record",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
}

...

{
  "name":"java.lang.reflect.RecordComponent",
  "methods":[
    {"name":"getName","parameterTypes":[] }, 
    {"name":"getType","parameterTypes":[] }
  ]
}
```

but still, during build of native image I'm getting:

```
Caused by: com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError$HostedError: New Method or Constructor found as reachable after static analysis: public java.lang.String a.b.c.D$Issue.d()
```

IIUC it means, that compiller found call to d(), which weren't discovered before (am I right?), but:

- why isn't it 'auto-discovered'? It's not reflection or anything that hard to understand.
- why is it considered as *new* if (as far as I understand) covered by explicit metadata?

what am I overlooking? Trivial replace with static inner class is working workaround, but I would like to understand why records does not work...

Comment: https://github.com/oracle/graal/pull/5643/files may give you some ideas

Comment: Thanks for reply. TBH, I have no idea what is in that commit. No motivation, no implications, ... no nothing but what what done in commit. So record components are not stored on heap, fine. But why, what does it mean, why should static class behave differently than record. I have no idea. Was it a bug, which was solved by this MR?

Comment: that PR is related to java records, connected issue is [here](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/6510) also there are many record issues at github, https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/4348 and https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/3687 so I think they are trying to implement agile way so records are supported but be aware you may have problems :) in case of problems just use classes.